# Google Tag Manager - Help setting up tags to track play button clicks and timestamps

Tags: google-tag-manager

Was wondering if someone could help me out or provide some guidance with some things I'm looking to do with Google Tag Manager.

I'm fairly new to GTM but I've already got two basic tags set up:

- Track All Page Views
- Track all Link Clicks

I've got the above two working and sending data to my Google Analytics account.
What I'm having trouble with is the following:
My website has a bunch of single pages that each have an audio player on them. I would like to track when a user does the following:

1. Clicks the Play Button
2. Clicks the Download Button

On top of that, I would like to:

3. Track the timestamp of the song when a user clicks the Pause Button or exits the page.

Here's an example of one of the pages I would like to implement these tags on: https://www.jimmypressplay.com/mashup-last-friday-night-i-wanna

For #1 and #2, I've tried a bunch of things with no success. I've messed around with the "Click - All Elements" and "Custom Event" Trigger Types and I've set the trigger to fire when the click element matches the div/button class of the play button. I've also messed around with setting up a custom variable (by using either the "Auto-Event Variable" or "DOM element" options). But none of that seems to work (but obviously I am probably doing something wrong).

For #3, I haven't tried tackling that yet, but I've noticed in the code in the "slider slider_is-active" div class it has an element ("aria-valuenow") that keeps track of the current timestamp, so I'm guessing there should be some way to return that timestamp if I am able to set it up as a custom variable somehow.

If anyone has some free time and could take a look and point me in the right direction, that would be great! Or if I need to provide more info, let me know.
Thanks!